# Row to column transformation in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to transform rows into columns in snowflake.
Loading file from the local.

Source :

| Element | Scale | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oral | Importance | 4.5 |
| Oral | Level | 4.8 |

Output Required:

| Element | Importance | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oral | 4.5 | 4.8 |

How can we transform data while loading from local/internal stage.
Or we need to load data first and then transform.